# BeautifulSoup Parsing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been struggling to parse out this tree using BeautifulSoup to get just the text I am looking for.  After prettifying the HTML I end up with a table I am interested in.

```
    <td>
       <a href="/inventoryCheck/16783169/?zip=93817">
        <h3>
         Product A
        </h3>
       </a>
       <a class="show_hide" href="/inventoryCheck/16783169/?zip=93817" style="color:red">
        Not Available
       </a>
       <br/>
       Available at roughly
       <a style="color:red">
        0%
       </a>
       of Stores Nationwide
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="padding:10px">
       <a href="/inventoryCheck/32201303/?zip=93817">
        <img src="/prod_image/32201303.jpg"/>
       </a>
      </td>
      <td>
       <a href="/inventoryCheck/32201303/?zip=93817">
        <h3>
         Product B
        </h3>
       </a>
       <a class="show_hide" href="/inventoryCheck/32201303/?zip=93817" style="color:red">
        Not Available
       </a>
       <br/>
       Available at roughly
       <a style="color:red">
        0%
       </a>
       of Stores Nationwide
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="padding:10px">
       <a href="/inventoryCheck/29236000/?zip=93817">
        <img src="/prod_image/29236000.jpg"/>
       </a>
      </td>
      <td>
       <a href="/inventoryCheck/29236000/?zip=93817">
        <h3>
         Product C
        </h3>
       </a>
       <a class="show_hide" href="/inventoryCheck/29236000/?zip=93817" style="color:red">
        Not Available
       </a>
       <br/>
       Available at roughly
       <a style="color:red">
        0%
       </a>
       of Stores Nationwide
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="padding:10px">
       <a href="/inventoryCheck/35536199/?zip=93817">
        <img src="/prod_image/35536199.jpg"/>
       </a>
      </td>
      <td>
       <a href="/inventoryCheck/35536199/?zip=93817">
        <h3>
         Product D
        </h3>
       </a>
       <a class="show_hide" href="/inventoryCheck/35536199/?zip=93817" style="color:red">
        Not Available
       </a>
       <br/>
       Available at roughly
       <a style="color:red">
        0%
       </a>
       of Stores Nationwide
      </td>
```

An 'h3' tag indicates a product so I want to grab the text within that tag, and if there is an h3 then I also want to look into the next 'a' tag and see if that product is available.

Ultimately in Python I just want a line with the name of the product and its availability.

I have tried using .children, .descendants etc, but am really getting nowhere.

Can anyone offer a clue please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for are the `.parent` and `.nextSibling` attributes. They help you navigate the tree relative to your `h3` tags.The important thing to remember about BeautifulSoup (and any HTML/XML/etc.) is that it's tree based. The rough structure of your HTML is like this:

```
td
├─ a
│  └─ h3
├─ a
├─ a
└─ br
```

So your `h3` is the child of the first `a`, and the "niece/nephew" of the `a` you want. So you need to get the `h3`'s parent's next sibling. The BeautifulSoup docs have a good section on [navigating the tree](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-the-tree).

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

testdata = """
Your data here
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(testdata)

items = []

for item in soup.find_all('h3'):
    name = item.text
    availability = item.parent.nextSibling.text

    items.append({'name': name, 'availability': availability})
```

You'll get an `items` array with dictionaries for each product:

```
 [{'name': u'Product A', 'availability': u'Not Available'},
  {'name': u'Product B', 'availability': u'Not Available'},
  {'name': u'Product C', 'availability': u'Not Available'},
  {'name': u'Product D', 'availability': u'Not Available'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, you want to find all `td` elements having an `h3` element inside - these would be your products. Then, you can get the availability from the `a` element having `show_hide` class and `inventoryCheck` inside `href`. Working code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

data = """
your HTML
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
for product in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag and tag.name == "td" and tag.h3):
    name = product.h3
    availability = product.find("a", class_="show_hide", href=lambda href: href and "inventoryCheck" in href)
    availability_stats = " ".join([item.get_text(strip=True) if isinstance(item, Tag) else item.strip()
                                   for item in availability.next_siblings])

    print(name.get_text(strip=True), availability.get_text(strip=True), availability_stats.strip())
```

For the provided sample HTML, it would print:

```
(u'Product A', u'Not Available', u'Available at roughly 0% of Stores Nationwide')
(u'Product B', u'Not Available', u'Available at roughly 0% of Stores Nationwide')
(u'Product C', u'Not Available', u'Available at roughly 0% of Stores Nationwide')
(u'Product D', u'Not Available', u'Available at roughly 0% of Stores Nationwide')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the product and availability you can use  a css selector, pull the h3 tags inside the td tags then use `find_next` to get the anchor:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(h,"html.parser")
h3s = soup.select("td  h3")
print([(h3.text.strip(), h3.find_next("a").text.strip()) for h3 in h3s])
```

Output:

```
[(u'Product A', u'Not Available'), (u'Product B', u'Not Available'), (u'Product C', u'Not Available'), (u'Product D', u'Not Available')]
```